# split data from user input

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

a string or text from user input into the application in the following format: {"id 1,name 1"} ex:{id_1},{name_1};{id_2},{name_2};In other words, the input string/text contains information on numerous candidates, each of which is separated by a semicolon. A comma is used to separate the candidate's name from their ID.I am trying to split data into 2 different arrays one being the id and the second being the name of the candidate. If possible without using anu other libraries?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A3_Q2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
//Welcome message displayed to the program displayed to the user
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple Electronic Voting System (SEVS):");
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

//Prompting the user for input for the program
        System.out.println("Please enter a String collection of electoral candidates below:");String candi=keyboard.nextLine();
        String cand[]= candi.split(";");
        
        
        
//Options displayed to user with codes coresponding to each one
        System.out.println("********************************");
        System.out.println("| Code >> Description          |");
        System.out.println("********************************");
        System.out.println("| 1 >> Display candidates      |");
        System.out.println("| 2 >> Vote a candidate        |");
        System.out.println("| 3 >> Add a new candidate     |");
        System.out.println("| 4 >> Display results         |");
        System.out.println("| 0 >> End SEVS                |");
        System.out.println("********************************");
```

Comment: Split the string "{id_1},{name_1};{id_2},{name_2};" at `;`. After that, loop through your array and split every element at `,`. Inside this loop you can add the first element to the ids array and the second element to the names array.

Comment: How would i go by this? im kind of new to java

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class A3_Q2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
//Welcome message displayed to the program displayed to the user
        
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple Electronic Voting System (SEVS):");
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

//Prompting the user for input for the program
        System.out.println("Please enter a String collection of electoral candidates below:");
        String candi=keyboard.nextLine();
        String cand[]= candi.split(";");
        String ids[] = new String[cand.length];
        String names[] = new String[cand.length];
        int index = 0;
        
        for(String candidate: cand){
            String[] c = candidate.split(",");
            ids[index] = c[0];
            names[index] = c[1];
            index++;
        }
//Options displayed to user with codes coresponding to each one
        System.out.println("********************************");
        System.out.println("| Code >> Description          |");
        System.out.println("********************************");
        System.out.println("| 1 >> Display candidates      |");
        System.out.println("| 2 >> Vote a candidate        |");
        System.out.println("| 3 >> Add a new candidate     |");
        System.out.println("| 4 >> Display results         |");
        System.out.println("| 0 >> End SEVS                |");
        System.out.println("********************************");
   }
}
```